# Actionscript 3.0 Error opening URL error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-ide

I am writing an AS3 application which requires downloading xml file from external server.I am trying to connect to the external server (while testing from my local machine) to load the file however The URLLoader is unable to load it and showing "Error opening URL ". However when I put the exact url in browser, the xml file is loaded properly. The server uses https.

Following are the code/settings I am using

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
xmlfile = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("<fullurl>"));
```

The eventlistener are set properly for the loader, and have been tested locally.
I am using FlashIDE and the publish setting is set to "Access Network Only".

The server which is being connected to serves the crossdomain.xml in the root directory and contains the followings.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
   <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="true"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I am unable to understand what is missing in my code/settings to make it work, after searching for very long time. 
I have tried to connect to other server using URLRequest and it seems to be working. For example following line doesn't show the earlier mentioned error

```
xmlfile = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("https://www.google.com"));
```

Comment: 1) Make sure you try to connect to a correct URL ;) 2) Your crossdomain.xml will only allow https connections. Do you try to connect over https ? Make sure the server does not block any connections (firewall?). 3) Add these event listeners to your URLLoader to see if you will get any hints in the errors that will pop up: HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS, IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR

Comment: What's the `<fullurl>`? What is the full error message?

Comment: Full url : https://mygamekb2-1674052566.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/Chips_On